# Call parameters in Powershell script in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I need to run a powershell script in a function called by Jenkins. When calling this function, two other parameters/variables are included. This is a sample of my code:

```
        powershell '''
            $Headers = @{"ApiKey"="$env:myKey"}
            $jsonBody = @{
                varOne= '$env:params.varOne'
                varTwo = '$env:params.varTwo'} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

            Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "myUrl" -Headers $Headers -Body $jsonBody
        '''
```

This is throwing a 'Bad Response' error. Note that if I hard code the values that are in the variable, the script works.
I also try to wrap the script with withEnv but I got the same issue:

```
    withEnv(["varOne=${params.varOne}, varTwo=${params.varTwo}"]) {
    powershell '''
        $Headers = @{"ApiKey"="$env:myKey"}
        $jsonBody = @{
            varOne= '$env:params.varOne'
            varTwo = '$env:params.varTwo'} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "myUrl" -Headers $Headers -Body $jsonBody
    '''
}
```

Finally, I know I could call these variables successfully if I was using double quote instead of single ones

```
powershell """
some ps1 script
"""
```

However, when I do that it says:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Headers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to template variables you need `"""` as I said in the question you deleted, but you need to escape the `$` on non templated variables

```
powershell """
        \$Headers = @{"ApiKey"="$env:myKey"}
        \$jsonBody = @{
            varOne= '$env:params.varOne'
            varTwo = '$env:params.varTwo'} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "myUrl" -Headers \$Headers -Body \$jsonBody
    """
```